# Ubuntu 16.04 Battery Drains to 50% in shutdown in 5-6 hours [HP pavilion Gaming Notebook]

Tags: dual-boot, power-management, shutdown, hp, battery

I have a dual boot system with windows 10. 
I use ubuntu most of the time and in the night when i shut it down with 90%-95% battery. Next morning when i open up the laptop, the battery is drained to 45%-50%.
I did face this only with ubuntu and not in windows.
My notebook is Hp Pavilion Gaming ak007tx.

Its a brand new laptop and I am very tensed about this problem.

Does anyone knows how to fix this

Comment: if you shutdown again when it drains to 50 % on ubuntu and run windows 10 is it still 50% or increase ??

Comment: I actually have a very similar problem on a Toshiba laptop with suspend - I'd be interested in any ideas, too.

Comment: Mohamed Slama  No bro its 50% only.